# how to iterate through a json that has multiple pages

Tags: python, json

I have created a program that iterates through a multi-page json object.

```
def get_orgs(token,url):
    part1 = 'curl -i -k -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer '
    final_url = part1 + token + '" ' + url 
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(final_url, shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    data = pipe.communicate()[0]
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        print line
        try:
            row = json.loads(line)
            print ("next page url ",row['next'])
        except :
            pass
    return row
my_data = get_orgs(u'MyBeearerToken',"https://data.ratings.com/v1.0/org/576/portfolios/36/companies/")
```

The json object is as below:

```
[{results: [{"liquidity":"Strong","earningsPerformance":"Average"}]
,"next":"https://data.ratings.com/v1.0/org/576/portfolios/36/companies/?page=2"}]
```

I am using 'next' key to iterate,but at times it points to "Invalid Page" ( a page that doesn't exist). Does JSON object have a rule about how many records are there on each page ? In that case , I will use that to estimate how many pages are possible.

EDIT: Adding more details
The json has just 2 keys ['results','next']. If there are multiple pages, then the 'next' key has the next page's url (`as you can see in the output above`). Else , it contains 'None'. 
But, problem is that at times, instead of 'None' , it points to the next page (which does not exist). So, I want to see if I can count the rows in Json and divide by a number to know how many pages the loop needs to iterate through.

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Your problem seems to be that you request some JSON from a server. The JSON contains an URL to the next dataset for lack of a better word. Are you having problems extracting the correct URL, or is the URL that you extract from the response incorrect? In the later case the problem is not in your code. Why are you using curl instead of a built-in python solution like [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html)?

Comment: Hi Maurice, thanks for your reply. I am sitting behind a proxy in my company and curl works fine. For urllib2 or requests, I get an authentication error.

Comment: @Maurice, I have edited the question to give more details about the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using urllib2 or urllib.request would be a much better option than curl in order to make the code easier to understand, but if that's a constraint - I can work with that ;-)

Assuming the json-response is all in one line (Otherwise your json.loads will throw an Exception), the task is pretty simple and this will allow you to fetch the amount of items behind the result key:

```
row = [{'next': 'https://data.ratings.com/v1.0/org/576/portfolios/36/companies/?page=2', 'results': [{'earningsPerformance':'Average','liquidity': 'Strong'}, {'earningsPerformance':'Average','liquidity': 'Strong'}]}]
result_count = len(row[0]["results"])
```

The alternative solution using httplib2 should look something like this (I didn't test this):

```
import httplib2
import json
h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
url = "https://data.ratings.com/v1.0/org/576/portfolios/36/companies/"
token = "Your_token"
try:
    response, content = h.request(
        url,
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization:Bearer': token}
    )
    # Convert the response to a string
    content = content.decode('utf-8') # You could get the charset from the header as well
    try:
        object = json.loads(content)
        result_count = len(object[0]["results"])
        # Yay, we got the result count!
    except Exception:
        # Do something if the server responds with garbage
        pass
except httplib2.HttpLib2Error:
    # Handle the exceptions, here's a list: https://httplib2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libhttplib2.html#httplib2.HttpLib2Error
    pass
```

For more on httplib2 and why its amazing I suggest reading [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/http-web-services.html#introducing-httplib2).